# Combining two associative arrays to avoid duplicates

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string like this, however I don't want the elements with same key twice.
Like in the case of second `C`, I want the `num` of the specific `status` be added to the parent one (like the new combined `C` should have `status: 0` with `num: 60883` (3223 + 57659) ). Basically, `C` should only occur once in my array. Same for rest of the elements.

```
[
   {
      "C":[
         {
            "status":"0",
            "num":"3223"
         },
         {
            "status":"1",
            "num":"45186"
         },
         {
            "status":"2",
            "num":"8310"
         },
         {
            "status":"3",
            "num":"82"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "C":[
         {
            "status":"0",
            "num":"57659"
         },
         {
            "status":"1",
            "num":"3017"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "F":[
         {
            "status":"0",
            "num":"1506"
         },
         {
            "status":"1",
            "num":"31253"
         },
         {
            "status":"2",
            "num":"1660"
         },
         {
            "status":"5",
            "num":"1017"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "F":[
         {
            "status":"0",
            "num":"34024"
         },
         {
            "status":"1",
            "num":"2167"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am using PHP for pushing the values, is there something I can do before I push the values inside to make sure no duplicates are there?

The PHP code is something like:

```
foreach ($Something as $something) {
    $data = array(
        'status' => $something->status,
        'num'    => $something->num,
    );

    $zone_data[$stringWhichIsGenerated][] = $data;  
}

// Probably I have to do something here...?
array_push($zone_parent, $zone_data);
```

I have been trying to come up with several stupid ways to fix it since the morning, but I havent been really fruitful till now.

I am outputting this using `json_encode()` on my array. This question might be a duplicate, but I really wasn't able to find anything useful to me.

Comment: `if(isset($yourarray[$path][$to][$whatever])){..increment with value ..} else {... create one ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on my comment, I think preventing the problem helps the need to actually make the array unique in the first place, especially as you're fortunate enough here that you're actually making the array initially.

### Test Data

```
class Foo {
    public $status;
    public $num;

    public function __construct( $status, $num ) {
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->num = $num;
    }
}

function generateRandomString( $length = 10 ) {
    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; $ranString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
         $ranString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];               
    return $ranString;
}

$Something = array();
for( $x = 0; $x < 3; $x++ ) {
    $Something[$x] = new Foo( $x, rand(0, 100));
}
```

### Keep Unique

```
$zone_data = array();
foreach( $Something as $something ) {
    $data = array(
       'status' => $something->status,
       'num'    => $something->num,
    );

    do { 
        $Key = generateRandomString( 1 );   
    } while (array_key_exists( $Key, $zone_data ));

    $zone_data[$Key][] = $data;
}
```

### Results

```
[V] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [status] => 0
                [num] => 72
            )
    )
[C] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [status] => 1
                [num] => 75
            )
    )
[B] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [status] => 2
                [num] => 6
            )
    )
```

Comment: I don't understand what it is doing. Plus, I also think it is create an infinite loop.

Comment: I do apologise, removed the `!` =)

Comment: @JohnSmith And imrpoved answer to hopefully give you an idea

Comment: Ha, thanks! I was able to fix this on my own by something else though. :) But still thanks a lot for your help!